# Following "The top priority now is to stop Lai Ching-te's visit to the United States." did China take any measures to try to do so?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, china, taiwan, embassy

Politico's August 12, 2023 [Taiwan’s VP defies Beijing with New York City transit stop](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/08/12/taiwans-vp-lai-ching-te-defies-beijings-wishes-with-new-york-city-transit-stop-00110967) includes:

> Lai, the leading presidential candidate in Taiwan’s upcoming election, is using the Big Apple stop to meet with members of the Taiwanese American community. **On Saturday, China began conducting a three-day military exercise in the East China Sea a few hundred miles from Taiwan — a typical show from Beijing to express its displeasure with the island’s foreign political activities.**
>
> **But China’s reaction was relatively muted given that China’s ambassador to the U.S., Xie Feng, told a crowd [at the Aspen Security Forum last month](http://us.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/dshd/202307/t20230721_11116037.htm) that aborting Lai’s stopovers was his “top priority.”** These travel visits often attract the eyes of watchers in Beijing and Washington, given their contentious nature for China, but American protocol dictates that they remain low key.

That links to a page in the Chinese embassy to the US website which begins:

> Ambassador Xie Feng had a fireside chat with a senior U.S. media professional at the Aspen Security Forum
>
> On July 19, 2023, Chinese Ambassador to the United States Xie Feng attended the Aspen Security Forum at invitation, and had a fireside chat with Steve Clemons, Founding Editor-at-large of Semafor. Ambassador Xie elaborated on China’s policies and positions on China-U.S. relations, China’s intention in development, the Taiwan question, U.S. technological suppression of China and other issues.

and the part to which Politico refers seems to be:

> On the Taiwan question, Ambassador Xie emphasized that Taiwan is China's Taiwan. It is an inalienable part of China’s territory. This is the first thing we need to bear in mind when handling Taiwan-related issues. No one cherishes more than the Chinese side peace and stability across the Taiwan Strait. And no one wishes more for peaceful reunification than us. There are two biggest threats to peace and stability across the Taiwan Strait now. First, the Taiwan authorities are seeking U.S. support for their independence agenda. They have refused to recognize the 1992 Consensus, and even denied their Chinese identity. Second, some forces in the United States are trying to use Taiwan to contain China. They have emboldened adventurism and provocation by “Taiwan independence” separatists. The path they are taking is very dangerous. This is something we should guard against.
>
> The Taiwan question is the most important and sensitive question in China-U.S. relations. The U.S. side should take concrete actions to deliver on President Biden’s statement that the United States does not support "Taiwan independence". **The most fundamental thing is to return to the one-China principle; the most important is to abide by the three Sino-U.S. joint communiques; and the most pressing is to oppose adventurism and provocation by "Taiwan independence" separatists. The top priority now is to stop Lai Ching-te's visit to the United States, which is like a "gray rhino" charging at us.**

Apparently the gray rhino has been charging for quite a while; Politico ends with:

> “It’s up to the Chinese how they want to play it,” said Daniel Russel<sup>1</sup>, a former senior Asia hand in the Obama administration. **“Every serious [Taiwan presidential] candidate in the past has come to the United States for kind of an informal base touch — there is nothing new, radical or different about this.”**

**Question:** Following China’s ambassador to the U.S., Xie Feng said that "The top priority now is to stop Lai Ching-te's visit to the United States." did China take any discernible measures to actually try to stop it?

Apparently as of August 13 Lai is in the US (New York) and plans to transit again with an overnight stay in San Francisco.

- Focus Taiwan; August 2, 2023 [Vice president to stop in New York, San Francisco on Paraguay trip](https://focustaiwan.tw/politics/202308020008)

---

<sup>1</sup>[Daniel Russel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_R._Russel)

Comment: They expressed their unhappiness and conducted military exercises. That is something that might potentially have stopped the visit. At the very least it will have some impact on how the visit is perceived.

Comment: What kind of measures do you imagine they could take to actually try to stop it? They could shoot down his plane, but this would almost certainly provoke a military response. I don't think "top priority" (which is almost certainly a rhetorical exaggeration) means that it's worth starting a war.

Comment: @Barmar How is what I think relevant here and why is "starting a war" the only possible option? If you can make a case for this please feel free to write it up as an answer!

Comment: I assumed you had some minimal understanding of how international relations work. How does any nation force anything to happen outside their direct jurisdiction?

Comment: @Barmar anyone with minimal understanding would know *there are many, many ways* to make things happen (or in this case not happen) besides starting a war. War is widely recognized as the choice of last resort when all else has failed. By itself that informs us that there are other choices.

Comment: OK, I admit it was somewhat hyperbolic. But practically everything international is either negotiation or coercion. There's very few ways to force anyone to do anything.

Comment: @Barmar besides forcing, one can also try to make something worth thier while (e.g. negotiating, bargaining etc.) though not necessarily in this case. And one can also consider tricking a party into doing (or not doing) something. This is why I asked if China had simply *taken any measures to try* to do so.